# How check if there is 2 or more elements with the same value in a multiset in O(N) time complexity?

Tags: c++

I have a multiset/ any container with some values
e.g. {1,2,3,4,5,5} --> this will return some value;
{1,2,3,4,5} --> will return some other value;

I am trying to find out if there are any duplicates in the container, in O(N)
time complexity.

Comment: [Copy unique values to another container](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique_copy), and compare the sizes. The copying is a linear (O(N)) operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `std::multiset` is an ordered container any duplicates would be consecutive. The [`std::adjacent_find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_find) algorithm searches for consecutive identical elements (linear complexity).

Here is a simple boolean function that tests for duplicate `int` values.

```
#include <algorithm>

bool has_duplicates(const std::multiset<int> &mset)
{
    return std::adjacent_find(mset.begin(), mset.end()) != mset.end();
}
```